# External javascript file not loading in iOS Chrome Mobile App (using Cordova)? Works fine in Android

Tags: ios, cordova, google-chrome-app

Any ideas here? I am using Google Polymer with Vulcanize in order to comply with Google's Content Security Policy and not use any inline Javascript in my index.html file, but while it appears to work on Android, it is broken when I try to run it in an iOS emulator.

Is there some iOS specific thing with external javascript files that I should know about? Or any ideas as to why this is happening? Any documentation or something would be helpful, I am only slightly familiar with iOS.

Even a way to get some sort of debugging screen working with xcode would be lovely. I'm using the cordova log plugin to try to get my console.logs to do anything, but nothing is showing up, so I'm just inferring that my external javascript isn't loading.

Comment: Check in safari and if its not loading then use safari dev tools for debugging.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know you could do this. It appears something is broken with Polymer and Safari after using Vulcanize on my index file. Now I can debug at least!